# Does my study design have randomization issues?

Tags: experiment-design, random-allocation, research-design

I am helping to design a study where participants will be randomized to one of three arms -- a control arm, treatment 1 or treatment 2.

Within each arm, they will then also receive either no counselling or weekly counselling. This is a 3*2 factorial design.

My colleague has proposed that the counselling provided could vary based on the mood disorder the participant has, which is identified during the screening for recruitment.

Every participant will have only one of four possible and distinct mood disorders to be included in the study.

I am concerned about this because it seems as if there is no longer true randomization. Or that it is no longer a 3*2 design.

I am new to this field and don't feel confident that I am correct. My questions are:

1. Does this study design as described have issues with randomization?
2. If it is a problem, is there a name for this type of problem or error?

Comment: In my opinion, if you are going to measure and separate based on mood disorder (4 categories) then it sounds like you are adding an additional factor for a 3x2x4 design.  Remember a good experiment is not random it is just conducted in a randomization order.